# Why doesn't the following code give the desired answer?

Tags: c++, c, int

Yesterday on an interview the interviewer asked me a question:

Why doesn't the following code give the desired answer?

```
int a = 100000, b = 100000;

long int c = a * b ;
```

The language is C.

I've told the interviewer that we count first the 100,000 * 100,000 as an int(overflow) and just then cast it to long.

Comment: I don't know which language you used, but I tried this with c# and it works properly. You tagged c#, c++ and c. Please be more specific

Comment: The question as is, without saying what the desired answer is sounds like some of the "It doesn't work" questions we see here on SO everyday and have to tediously milk for details. It seems to produce the answer *I* desire. @Christian: are you sure? My C# compiler refuses to compile this code.

Comment: I tried it in Visual C++ 9 and the result is 100M as I would expect. What's wrong?

Comment: try to multiply two integers in a way that the result would not fit an integer then you will notice...

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Well since he said c, c++ or c# I changed the code slightly: from "long int" to "long" and to "int". both versions work in c#

Comment: So, did the interviewer tell you what the expected answer is, or did she/he leave you wondering?

Comment: So what did you answer? What answers did you consider? Did you ask the interviewer any questions, like how large an int is on the machine where it gives the wrong answer?

Comment: Hm so you answered the question correctly @Vadiklk. What do you want us to say? :D

Comment: Ask if I was right, she didn't tell me if I was

Comment: Well I would say yes, you are right. But you could try to write this program and see yourself ;)

Comment: True, that what was amusing, my compiler told me it was okay, thats why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the clue would be an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) to occur, but with such low values, I don't see that happening.

Maximum (positive) value for int (usually 32bit) is: *2,147,483,647*

The result of your calculation is: *100,000,000*

UPDATE:

With your updated question: `100000 * 100000` instead of `10000 * 10000` results in *10,000,000,000*, which **will** cause an overflow to occur. This value is then cast to a long afterwards.

To prevent such an overflow the correct approach would be to cast one of the two values in the multiplication to a long (usually 64bit). E.g. `(long)100000 * 100000`

Comment: In C# it wouldn't, because `int` is always 32 bits signed. In C or C++, `int` can be as small as 8 bits, depending on the machine.

Comment: @Thomas: Yup, just realized that, so I quickly added the _"in general"_. :)

Comment: @Thomas: how can int be as small as 8 bits and hold integer values in the range [-32768,32767]?

Comment: `<nitpick>` It doesn't hold "in general" at all, but only in specific cases. The word "usually" might be more appropriate. `</nitpick>`

Comment: @Martinho: Pardon me, I was wrong. The minimum seems to be 16 bits.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris - The question has been edited so that the result is 10,000,000,000 causing an overflow with 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 5):

That's cause it first calculates it as an int, and only then casts it into a long variable.(so it first overflows as an integer and then becomes a long)
the code should be

```
long int c = a*(long int)b;
```

Comment: it will most likely still give the correct answer tho. the questions is faulty; it should be "why would you raise your eye browns" ;)

Comment: @stefan exactly! This particular piece of code works, but the general idea of an overflow is maybe what the interviewer was after.

Answer (score 3):

`100000*100000` is `10000000000` (`10,000,000,000`) which is greater than the maximum value a 32bit `int` can represent (`2,147,483,647`), thus it [overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

`a*b` is still an `int`, it's not a `long int`, since the members of expression `a*b` are both of type `int`, thus they aren't converted to `long int`: this conversion will only happen after `a*b` has been evaluated, when the result is assigned `c`. If you want the result of `a*b` to be `long int` you need to convert at least one of the operands as `long int`:

```
long int c = (long int)a * (long int)b.
```

Moreover `long int` could be of the same size of `int` (it could be represented on 32 bits too): this is most likely to happen with 32 bit application where, usually, `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long int) == 4`.

If you need `c` to be of 64 bits you should better use a variable like [`int64_t`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/int64_t), that ensures you to be of 64 bits.